# What does this statement return in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
to_date({},'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

I see a to_date function used with an empty string as shown in one of the SQL code pieces I'm validating. What does an empty string passed into to_date function in Oracle SQL return?

Comment: The query as shown will result in an error because `{}` is invalid

Comment: `ORA-00936: missing expression`

Comment: Why don't you try and see?

Comment: Is `{}` supposed to be a placeholder for a bind parameter?

Comment: Is your code pre-processed before executed?

Comment: the braces are used as escape sequence delimiters in text queries. this is certainly no text query, so maybe you are looking at a template where a replacement is supposed to be made before execution?

Comment: It's a placeholder.

Comment: so to answer this, we need to know what gets substituted at runtime, what you expect, and what is the outcome. in case the parameter value was NULL, the result would be NULL as well. there is no "empty string" anywhere involved.